# java increment operation not incrementing

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10;
    x = x++;
    x = x++;
    x = x++;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Why is the output 10 when the expected output is 13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post increment operator `x++` returns the original value of `x`. Therefore `x=x++` assigns the old value of `x` back to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you weant to do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10;
    x++;
    x++;
    x++;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "Why is the output 10 when the expected output is 13".